# Where is the Windows 10 USB Serial Device Driver located in the device manager and how do I reconfigure it?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, embedded

Basically I am trying to program my TINYFPGA. I was able to download the TINYFPGA program and associated libraries. However as soon as I tried to connect my TINYFPGA with my laptop that is where I am stuck. specifically "apio drivers --serial-enable"
This is the guide I am following:

https://tinyfpga.com/bx/guide.html

These forum posts provides the context of the problem:

https://forum.core-electronics.com.au/t/tinyfpga-bx-user-guide-stuck-on-programming/8596

https://forum.core-electronics.com.au/t/power-and-data-usb-for-my-tinyfpga/8650

From what people have already told me it seems that the  Windows 10 USB Serial Device Driver is not communicating with my TINYFPGA so the Windows 10 USB Serial Device Driver needs to be reconfigured so it will communicate with my TINYFPGA. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you verified your micro-usb cable supports data and is not a charging-only cable?

Comment: Is there a way I can verify?

Comment: In the forum posts I used "apio system --lsserial" does that check the micro-usb cable itself or only the connection?

Comment: I don't know anything about that device or the commands.  I'd suggest trying other cables or buying one that's specifically labeled as being data capable.